# JavaScript: How do I reference an object property in an object key?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I get an error because JavaScript does not like the dot in videos.id.  Is there a way around this?

Assuming I have an array:

```
var videos = [
    {
        "id": 65432445,
        "title": "The Chamber"
    },
    {
        "id": 675465,
        "title": "Fracture"
    },
    {
        "id": 70111470,
        "title": "Die Hard"
    },
    {
        "id": 654356453,
        "title": "Bad Boys"
    }
];
```

// and this is in a function

```
return videos.map(function(vids){
    return {videos.id : vids.title};  // videos.id does not work
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use variables as object keys in combination with the shorthand object constructor. You need to construct the object first and then use square bracket notation like this:

```
return videos.map(function(vid){
    var ret = {};
    ret[vid.id] = vid.title;
    return ret;
});
```

But this would give you a structure like

```
[{675465: "The Chamber"}, ...]
```

Whereas you probably want to do something like this

```
var vids = {};
videos.forEach(function (vid) {
    vids[vid.id] = vid.title;
});
```

which results in a structure like this:

```
{675465: "The Chamber", ...}
```

Allowing you to access the videos by id:

```
console.log(vids[675465]); // outputs "The Chamber"
```

Answer (score 0):

In map literals, the key is always interpreted as a string. The only way to use dynamic key is to use bracket notation.

Your can try this:

```
videos.map(function(vids) {var x={}; x[vids.id]=vids.title; return x; })
```

Answer (score -1):

This is because `videos` is an array of objects, each with an `id` property. It does not have its own `id`.

The way you would access the `id` of one of its elements is like this:

`videos[i].id`

I assume that this is what you are wanting:

```
return videos.map(function(vids){
    var vid = {};
    vid[vids.id] = vids.title; 
    return vid;
});
```